# Mul() Broadcast levels from Multi Index

Tags: pandas

Attempting to use a multiply operation with a multi index.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'Alpha': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
   ,'Beta':tuple('ABCDEFGHI')
   ,'C': np.random.randint(1,10,9)
   ,'D': np.random.randint(100,200,9)
 }

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.set_index(['Alpha','Beta'],inplace=True)
df = df.stack() #it's now a series
df.index.names = df.index.names[:-1] + ['Gamma']

ser = pd.Series(data = np.random.rand(9))
ser.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(range(1,10),np.repeat('C',9)))
ser.index.names = ['Alpha','Gamma']

print df
print ser

foo = df.mul(ser,axis=0,level = ['Alpha','Gamma'])
```

So my dataframe which became a series looks like

```
Alpha  Beta  Gamma
1      A     C          7
             D        188
2      B     C          7
             D        110
3      C     C          2
             D        124
4      D     C          4
             D        153
5      E     C          9
             D        178
6      F     C          6
             D        196
7      G     C          1
             D        156
8      H     C          1
             D        184
9      I     C          3
             D        169
```

And my series looks like

```
Alpha  Gamma
1      C       0.8731
2      C       0.6347
3      C       0.4688
4      C       0.5623
5      C       0.4944
6      C       0.5234
7      C       0.9946
8      C       0.7815
9      C       0.1219
```

In my `multiply` operation I want to broadcast on index levels `'Alpha'` and `'Gamma'`

but i get this error message:

> TypeError: Join on level between two MultiIndex objects is ambiguous

Comment: I can't tell if that should work or not.  I mean, I can tell what your code is hoping to do and it seems reasonable but I'm just not sure how this is implemented behind the scenes.  FWIW, you could workaround it with this:  `df.loc[:,:,'C'] * ser.loc[:,'C']`

Comment: True that. My example is a little contrived, Consider if the bottom row on the series read | Alpha =9 | Gamma = D | data = 0.1219 | i would hope that would on the multiply as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?  Perhaps it's the extra 'Beta' column in df but not ser that causes the problem?

(Note:  this is using df as updated in @Dickster's answer, not as in the original question)

```
df2 = df.reset_index().set_index(['Alpha','Gamma'])

df2[0].mul(ser)

Alpha  Gamma
1      C          2.503829
       D               NaN
2      C          5.028208
       D               NaN
3      C          0.842322
       D               NaN
4      C          0.198101
       D               NaN
5      C          0.800745
       D               NaN
6      C          1.936523
       D               NaN
7      C          2.507393
       D               NaN
8      C          4.846258
       D               NaN
9      C               NaN
       D        147.233378
```

Comment: perfect thanks.  I'd probably drop the Beta level like this: df.index = df.index.droplevel(level='Beta')
then df.mul(ser,axis=0)

Comment: Yeah, that's probably better although with the reset_index/set_index you could do it as a one-liner if you wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

So imagine I have this, where I now have a 'D' in Gamma in the series "ser":

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
d = {'Alpha': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
   ,'Beta':tuple('ABCDEFGHI')
   ,'C': np.random.randint(1,10,9)
   ,'D': np.random.randint(100,200,9)
 }

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.set_index(['Alpha','Beta'],inplace=True)
df = df.stack() #it's now a series
df.index.names = df.index.names[:-1] + ['Gamma']

ser = pd.Series(data = np.random.rand(9))


idx = list(np.repeat('C',8))
idx.append('D')

ser.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(range(1,10),idx))
ser.index.names = ['Alpha','Gamma']

print df
print ser

df_A = df.unstack('Alpha').mul(ser).stack('Alpha').reorder_levels(df.index.names)
print df_A


df_dickster77 = df.unstack('Alpha').mul(ser.unstack('Alpha')).stack('Alpha').reorder_levels(df.index.names)
print df_dickster77
```

Output is this:

```
Alpha  Beta  Gamma
1      A     C          6
             D        120
2      B     C          9
             D        118
3      C     C          6
             D        184
4      D     C          1
             D        111
5      E     C          1
             D        128
6      F     C          2
             D        129
7      G     C          8
             D        114
8      H     C          7
             D        150
9      I     C          3
             D        168
dtype: int32
Alpha  Gamma
1      C        0.417305
2      C        0.558690
3      C        0.140387
4      C        0.198101
5      C        0.800745
6      C        0.968262
7      C        0.313424
8      C        0.692323
9      D        0.876389
dtype: float64
```

output A:  inadvertent multiplication

```
Gamma                      C           D
Alpha Beta Gamma                        
1     A    C        2.503829         NaN
           D       50.076576         NaN
2     B    C        5.028208         NaN
           D       65.925400         NaN
3     C    C        0.842322         NaN
           D       25.831197         NaN
4     D    C        0.198101         NaN
           D       21.989265         NaN
5     E    C        0.800745         NaN
           D      102.495305         NaN
6     F    C        1.936523         NaN
           D      124.905743         NaN
7     G    C        2.507393         NaN
           D       35.730356         NaN
8     H    C        4.846258         NaN
           D      103.848392         NaN
9     I    C             NaN    2.629167
           D             NaN  147.233378
```

output df_dickster77: Its correct multiplication lining up on C's and D.
However 8 x D NaNs lost and 1 x C NaN lost

```
Alpha  Beta  Gamma
1      A     C          2.503829
2      B     C          5.028208
3      C     C          0.842322
4      D     C          0.198101
5      E     C          0.800745
6      F     C          1.936523
7      G     C          2.507393
8      H     C          4.846258
9      I     D        147.233378
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to do it ATM. At some point a more concise may be implemented.

```
In [21]: df.unstack('Alpha').mul(ser).stack('Alpha').reorder_levels(df.index.names)
Out[21]: 
Gamma                      C
Alpha Beta Gamma            
1     A    C        6.761867
           D      171.944612
2     B    C        0.154139
           D        6.371062
3     C    C        2.311870
           D       42.898041
4     D    C        0.390920
           D        9.479801
5     E    C        3.484439
           D       72.011743
6     F    C        0.740913
           D       50.382061
7     G    C        3.459497
           D       60.541203
8     H    C        0.467012
           D       19.030741
9     I    C        0.071290
           D       11.620286
```

Comment: need to unstack the series "ser" as well?

Comment: that doesn't do anything

Comment: The D values have been inadvertently multiplied by the series